# Anaconda3 Cython: gcc cannot find -lpthread, -lc

Tags: python, linker, pthreads, anaconda, cython

I'm running Anaconda3 with python3.6.5 on Xubuntu 16.04. I want to run the simple Cython example [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) but ran straight into a wall.

```
$ cat helloworld.pyx 
print("Hello World")

$ cat setup.py 
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)

$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling helloworld.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing helloworld.pyx
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
gcc -pthread -B /home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/helloworld.o
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/helloworld.o -o /home/j/gits/proj/fitting_multipoles/test/helloworld.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Tried to update all conda packages with `conda update --all`, didn't help. Did `conda install cython`, didn't help. I tried to run the gcc commands from the output message in the terminal. The first is fine, only the second one raises the errors. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the "gcc packages" installed ? ... `sudo apt install g++ libc6-dev linux-libc-dev`

Comment: Yes they are installed. But I found a workaround. Inside the `compiler_compat` dir there is only a linker `ld` which doesn't do the job apparently. I removed `-B /home/j/OFFICIAL/anaconda3/compiler_compat` from the second gcc-command and ran it in the terminal and that works. However all the regular commands work for a colleague with similar configuration so something subtle might be going on.

Comment: Can you work without Anaconda? E.g., use the normal (system) Python3, with Cython installed?

Comment: Yes in principle. But i prefer to have a dedicated package manager and anaconda should work. In the end I removed my old anaconda and reinstalled the latest version. Then it worked. I never figured out the cause.